# How can i override create_export_query function on the Calls module

Tags: sugarcrm

I like to add columns accounts.name and assigned_username to the exporting CSV on the Calls module. I can do that by editing the function create_export_query on the modules/Calls/Call.php

But I want this to be done on upgrade safe manner. I am using SugarCRM Pro 6.2 version

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, it is currently not possible to "override"/extend any sugarBean classes. Currently SugarCRM only facilitates upgrade-safe customizing to vardefs, languages, shortcuts, layouts, web services, and controllers+controller methods.

- Metadata customizing: [documentation](http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/support/documentation/SugarProfessional/6.2/-docs-Developer_Guides-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.2.0-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.2.1_html.html#9003184)
- Web Services: [documentation](http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/support/documentation/SugarProfessional/6.2/-docs-Developer_Guides-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.2.0-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.2.1_html.html#9001772)
- Controller customizing: [documentation](http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/support/documentation/SugarProfessional/6.2/-docs-Developer_Guides-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.2.0-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.2.1_html.html#9002188)

I'd properly make a custom module, which mimicks or extends the call module's export function in order to make it upgrade safe. ([documentation](http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/support/documentation/SugarProfessional/6.2/-docs-Developer_Guides-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.2.0-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.2.1_html.html#9003315))